# Prove $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $A_a$ is closed and $f|A_a$ is continuous for any $a$ and $\text{{$A_a$}}$ is locally finite collection

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha} \rightarrow Y$ be a function between the topological spaces Y and $X=\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}$. Suppose that $f|A_{\alpha}$ is a continuous function for every $\alpha$ and that $\text{{$A_{\alpha}$}}$ is locally finite collection. Suppose that $A_{\alpha}$ is closed for every $\alpha$.

Show that: $f$ is continuous.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We denote  $f_{\alpha}:=f/A_{\alpha}$. Let $F$ be a closed subset of $Y$, we have 
$f^{-1}(F)=\cup_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}^{-1}(F)$, now for each $\alpha$, $f_{\alpha}^{-1}(F)$ is a closed subset  $A_{\alpha}$ hence it is a closed subset (in $X$). To finish we want to show that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed. Let $x\in \overline{f^{-1}(F)}$, and fix a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ which intersect only a finitely many of the sets  $A_{\alpha_1},\ldots,A_{\alpha_d}$, it is clear that each neighborhood $W$ of $x$ intersect $\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)$, hence $x\in \overline{\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)}=\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)\subset f^{-1}(F)$.

Comment: For me, It's not clear why every neighborhood $W$ of $x$ intersect $\cup_{i=1}^d f^{-1}_{a_i}(F)$ in a point $y$ different than $x$ (So $x$ belongs to limit points of the union hence, it belongs to the closure of the union as you have already mentioned). Any clarifications? @Hamou

Comment: Why $y$ must be different than $x$?

Comment: For $x$ to be in the closure of the union. either $x$ is in the union itself or it's in the limit points of the union. to be in the limit points of the union , every neighborhood containing $x$ must intersect the union in a point different than $x$ itself. this is the definition of limit point. @Hamou

Comment: $W\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, it intersect $f^{-1}(F)=\cup_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}^{-1}(F)$ but for $\alpha\neq \alpha_i$ we have $V\cap f_{\alpha}^{-1}(F)=\emptyset $ because $f_{\alpha}^{-1}(F)\subset A_{\alpha}$ $V\cap A_{\alpha}=\emptyset$ (by definition of $V$), this show that $V\cap W$ intersect $\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)$, hence $W$ intersect $\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)$. Conclusion; each neighborhood $W$ of $x$ intersect $\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)$, then $x\in \overline{\cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)}$ which is closed so $x\in \cup_{i=1}^df_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(F)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense now,At last! شكرا جزيلا لك @Hamou

Comment: I think that your answer can be improved( organising it more) , Do you mind me improving it now( after understanding it)? @Hamou

Answer (score 1):

Let $C\subset Y$ be any closed set. To prove continuity of $f$, it is to be shown that $f^{-1}(C)$ is a closed set.

Note that $f^{-1}(C)=\cup_\alpha (f^{-1}(C)\cap A_\alpha)=\cup_\alpha f|A_\alpha^{-1},$ where each of the sets in union is a closed set in $X$ as $A_\alpha$'s are given to be closed.

Take any $t\in \rm cl$$(f^{-1}(C)).$  By locally finiteness property, there exists a neighbourhood $U_t$ of $t$ and finitely many indices $\alpha_i, i=1,2,...,n$ such that $U_t\cap A_\alpha=\emptyset$ for all $\alpha \notin \{\alpha_i: 1\le i\le n\}$. Note that $U_t=\cup_{k=1}^n (U_t\cap A_{\alpha_k})$.

For any neighbourhood $V_t$ of $t$, $V_t\cap U_t$ is also a neighbourhood of $t$. Also, $U_t\cap V_t\cap f^{-1}(C)=\cup_{k=1}^n (U_t\cap V_t\cap f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C))=V_t\cap (\cup_k(U_t\cap f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C)))\subset V_t\cap  (\cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C))$.

Since $U_t\cap V_t\cap f^{-1}(C)$ is non empty (as $t$ is in closure of $f^{-1}(C)$), it follows that $V_t\cap(\cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C)) $ is non empty. Since $V_t$ is arbitrary neighbourhood of $t$, it follows that $t\in \rm cl$$(\cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C))$, which is a closed set by remark in the second paragraph. It follows that $\rm cl$$(\cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C))= \cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C)$. So $t\in \cup_k f|_{A_{\alpha_k}}^{-1}(C)\subset f^{-1}(C)\implies t\in f^{-1}(C).$ Since $t\in \rm cl$$(f^{-1}(C))$  was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that

$\rm cl$$(f^{-1}(C))=f^{-1}(C)\implies f^{-1}(C)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a function $f:X \to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous iff $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed for every closed set $A$ of $Y$.

What are the closed sets of $X = \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$? Why is it necessary for $\{A_\alpha\}$ to be locally finite collection?

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: Let $W\subset X$ be such that for all $\alpha\;W\cap A_\alpha$ is open in $A_\alpha$. Then $W$ is an open subset of $X$.

Proof: Let $p\in W$. Since $\{A_\alpha\}$ is locally finite, there is an open neighborhood $p\in O$, such that $O$ intersects only finitely many $A$'s, say $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Of all those $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, say $p$ lies in $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ where $m\leq n$. Since $A_{m+1}\cup\ldots\cup A_n$ is closed in $X$ and does not contain $p$, there is an open $O'\subset O$ that contains $p$ and does not intersect $A_{m+1},\ldots,A_n$.

For $i=1,\ldots,m$, $W\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ and contains $p$, thus there is an open $V_i\subset X$ containing $p$, such that $V_i\cap A_i\subset W\cap A_i$. We claim that $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^mV_i\right)\cap O'\subset W.$$To see this, let $q$ be some point in LHS. Since $q\in O'$, we have $q\in A_i$ for some $i=1,\ldots,m$, thus $q\in A_i\cap V_i\subset W$.

This should be enough.

Comment: Why is it true that there is an open $V_i\subset X$ containing $p$ such that $V_i \cap A_i \subset W \cap A_i$ ? @Amitai Yuval

Comment: Well, good question. It is right only for those $A_i$s which contain $p$. Thanks! I need to edit.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Thank you but I think it's not clear how do you know that such subset $O'$ exists. It's also not clear why $V_i$ exists. Could you provide more explanation please? @Amitai Yuval

Comment: $O'$ can be defined to be $O\setminus A_{m+1}\setminus\ldots\setminus A_n$. About $V_i$: $W\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ and contains $p$, thus there is $V_i'$ open in $A_i$ which contains $p$ and is contained in $W\cap A_i$. By definition of the induced topology we have $V_i'=V_i\cap A_i$ where $V_i$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Can we define $O'$ to be $O - \cup_{i=m+1}^n A_i$?. the union is closed and $O$ is open so. $O - \cup_{i=m+1}^n A_i$ is open. I think of this definition as yours is not clear as a result of the presence of parentheses. Anyway, $O'$ is clear if my definition works. Do you use $\subset$ for strict inclusion or for the possibility that it may be equal?@Amitai Yuval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16461/discussion-between-amitai-yuval-and-maths-lover).

Comment: Do you mind continuing the discussion about this way of answering the question?@Amitai Yuval

Answer (score 0):

$f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff for every $x \in X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ neighbourhood of $f(x)$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq X$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Given $x \in X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ neighbourhood of $f(x)$, by the local finiteness property, we have a neighbourhood $W \subseteq X$ such that $x \in W$ and $W$ only intersects a finite number of $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$. That implies that $W \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i $.

It is relatively easy to check that $f|_W$ is continuous, given that $f|_{A_i}$ is continuous. So, there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq W$ (open in the subset topology of W) such that $f|_W(U) \subseteq V$. This implies $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Is $U$ open in the original topology? Yes, as $W$ is open, $U$ is also open in the original topology.